# Python imports confusion

Tags: python, import, package

I've got a strange issue with importing a module. I've got a virtualenv setup and one module is available in `{env}/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkgname`. There is a `__init__.py` file and `pkgname.py` inside.

Now, if I run `{env}/bin/python` and execute `import pkgname.pkgname`, it works just fine. But if I create a script in `{env}/bin/pkgname.py` with contents:

```
#!{env}/bin/python

import pkgname.pkgname

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pkgname.pkgname.run()
```

this fails trying to import the same file again (since the package and the file have the same name). How can I disable looking in the same directory? Or how can I force the import to first look at the global packages?

Alternatively, what's the "proper" way of doing this? Just for consistency, I'd rather call my startup script the same as the actual package it's trying to run.

Comment: This is why we don't put extensions on executables in public directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it pkgname. Done. OK, then it won't start if you doubleclick in it WIndows, but that's usually not a problem.

Comment: Also, you have to move the file to some location like "scripts/pkgname", otherwise it will collide with "pkgname" package itself. And it works.

Comment: Right, in this case it's in {env}/bin, as mentioned in the question. That means /usr/local/bin or something like that. And I usually have my packages in src/pkgname, so no pb there. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify sys.path. It's just a list of paths to search and the current folder should be the first entry. Your file should run if you move the current folder to the end of the list. But I general I would not do something like that without a VERY good reason. Isn't it possible to rename your file name.py, runpkgname.py or something like that?

Comment: Or just remove the .py extension so it no longer has a valid module name.